# bash reboot command not found

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to execute a script on server. When I do `crontab -l` I get `@reboot cd my_project_path; ./start.sh` on terminal.

However when I do `@reboot cd my_project_path; ./start.sh` I get `-bash: @reboot: command not found`. How do I include reboot command in bash? Sorry if this is a very basic question, but I am not master in bash.

Comment: `@reboot` isn't part of the command, it's when to run it (after reboot).

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

There isn't a command `@reboot`. I think you're looking for

```
shutdown -r now
```

or (possibly)

```
/sbin/reboot
```

which will reboot your machine. However, in `crontab` a @reboot is a scheduled time, so that's the command it would run when your system has just rebooted... so perhaps you really just wanted

```
cd my_project_path; ./start.sh
```

Comment: I tried "/sbin/reboot cd my_project_path; ./start.sh" and now it's rebooting my whole system. So as I understand, it will execute ./start.sh after restart right?

Comment: Try this: `su -l` then type `reboot` and it works, can you explain that please?

Answer (score 1):

**@reboot** in crontab means "Do that / execute that on server boot"